# JUnit cannot find wsdl in dependency jar

Tags: java, maven, soap, junit4

I have a project that uses external library client jar. This jar contains soap client.

I would like to build a jUnit test for this, but when I run the test it throws an exception like `Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/C:/Development/project/wsdl/clientService.wsdl`

The jar contains wsdl under `META-INF\wsdl\`.

The funny thing is that when I deploy my project war, the service client works. I just can't make it work under junit.

Comment: can you post your junit test code

Comment: There is no point in pasting the code if this only utilizes the code contained in the jar.
`String targetEndpoint = AppProps.strGetter("registration.service.url");
if (registrationClient == null) {
 registrationClient = new registrationClient(targetEndpoint);
 
 registrationClient.getServiceRegistration();
}`

Comment: Your classpath is different when you run the deployed code from when you run it in a junit.  How are you running the junit test?  Is it with an IDE or with a build framework like maven?

Comment: `mvn test` usually, also tried running JUnit in Eclipse